# How to get tag with attribute containing a nbsp ("non breaking space")?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

Hello I am trying to get a tag that contain a value with non-breaking-space (nbsp) but when I do something like this:

```
a_url=soup.find_all('a', {"aria-label":"Siguiente&nbsp;"})
```

`a_url` return a empty list

how can I do to get the real value=?

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour] and read [ask] to improve, [edit] and format your questions. Thanks

Comment: Thank you @HedgeHog it help me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are searching for the `href` of "next page button" you can get it with these `selector` (prerequisite - it is the only one @ [website](https://mx.indeed.com/jobs?q=ingeniero&start=20)):

```
soup.select_one('a[aria-label*="Siguiente"]')['href']
```

#### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('''<a href="/jobs?q=ingeniero&amp;start=30&amp;pp=gQAtAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABtmO50gBfAQEBChquI8zsEUMb97LmWiIyJ6B9BupjjNHe0wHVJkxir7vk5faUnfGbH8SIKViz3xGntfsggaFcG0AVf914ketkZJK-TUcyKlIrQmiKVG-Mkh5cMa0vUE4tVGeMixwAAA" aria-label="Siguiente&nbsp;»" data-pp="gQAtAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABtmO50gBfAQEBChquI8zsEUMb97LmWiIyJ6B9BupjjNHe0wHVJkxir7vk5faUnfGbH8SIKViz3xGntfsggaFcG0AVf914ketkZJK-TUcyKlIrQmiKVG-Mkh5cMa0vUE4tVGeMixwAAA" onmousedown="addPPUrlParam &amp;&amp; addPPUrlParam(this);" rel="nofollow"><span class="pn"><span class="np"><svg width="24" height="24" fill="none"><path d="M10 6L8.59 7.41 13.17 12l-4.58 4.59L10 18l6-6-6-6z" fill="#2D2D2D"></path></svg></span></span></a>''', "lxml")

soup.select_one('a[aria-label*="Siguiente"]')['href']
```